# How does Asp.net Ajax event handle works together with DOM event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, dom, asp.net-ajax

All, I just want to know how does `Asp.net Ajax` event handle works together with `DOM` event. Say you have the code like below.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebAppAjax.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <input id="state" type="text" value=""  />
        <input id="Departments" type="text" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var departments = null;
    Sys.Application.add_load(page_load);
    Sys.Application.add_unload(page_unload);
    function page_load(sender, e) {
        departments = $get("Departments");
        $addHandler(departments, "blur", departments_onblur);
    }
    function page_unload(sender, e) {
        $removeHandler(departments, "blur", departments_onblur);
    }

    function departments_onblur(sender, e) {
        $get("state").value = "onblur";
        if (typeof (departments.blur) != "undefined") {
            departments.blur();
        }
        else {
            alert("underfined");
        }
    }
    function department_jsblur() {
        alert('jsblur');
    }
    //-->
</script>


protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    Departments.Attributes.Add("onblur", "department_jsblur();");
    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

the event handler `$addHandler(departments, "blur", departments_onblur);` doesn't overwrite the event handler `Departments.Attributes.Add("onblur", "department_jsblur();");`.
They both works.
Could anyone please help to explain how `Asp.net Ajax` make it ? thanks.

Comment: see the generated view source and navigate to your Department inputbox and you'll see something like this. <input id="Departments" type="text" onblur='department_jsblur();' />. addHandler, as the name says "add" only adds additional event not overriding it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically when you use the native javascript 'element.addEventListener(...)' method, it doesn't overwrite the older event handler, but simply adds another one. This is also the method that `$addHandler(...)` uses internally.
Check out the explanation for the W3C event registration model given [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html).

With this basic information, we can look at the code that you have mentioned:

```
Departments.Attributes.Add("onblur", "department_jsblur();");
```

is server side code that is used to create the html. It uses the traditional way of adding event handler resulting in HTML like `<textbox onblur='department_jsblur();' />`

The `$addHandler(departments, "blur", departments_onblur);` is the javascript that is executed once the html has been rendered in the browser window and the traditional event handler has been attached. It uses the `element.addEventListener('eventType', callbackMethod)` API provided by the language to add additional handlers.

Internally, the multiple handlers assigned to an element are stored in an array, and when the event is raised, all the handlers are executed one after the other.